# Adding an array of values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is the json data I have

```
{
"data" : 
    {
        "Count" : ["1","2","3","4", "5"]

    }

}
```

How can I use jQuery to get the result as

```
"Result" : ["1", "3","6","10", "15"]
```

Comment: But i need to pass the result in the format as i have mentioned before to use it as an json object.

Comment: Can't you make the counts to be numbers instead of strings? That would simplify the task a bit

Comment: @user2450679, since you liked my answer can you mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

No need for jQuery, a primitive loop will do that:

```
// Either
var obj = {"data":{"Count":["1","2","3","4","5"]}}
// or
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

var arr = obj.data.Count,
    res = [],
    acc = 0;
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    res[i] = String(acc += Number(arr[i]));
obj.data.Result = res;
```

Or, if you only want to add the counts to their previous (single) one only, use

```
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    res[i] = String(+arr[i] + (i && +arr[i-1]));
```

Comment: Using the `Number` and `String` constructor functions like this is unnecessary and has potential problems. Prefer `parseInt` to `Number`; and there doesn't seem to be any need to cast the values back to a `String`.

Comment: @founddrama, I think Bergi was just trying to do the work of actually match the question's odd requirement of it being strings.

Comment: @founddrama: What potential problems do you see? Only difference would be `Number` accepting floats as well. I don't *like* to use them too, but that's the format requested by the OP - and using the named constructors does highlight that issue nicely :-)

Comment: @DanielGimenez - that occurred to me, but it seems like an unnecessary step, as the numbers are easily cast to strings on-demand on the client-side. Turning them back in to strings just means extra work performed on the `Result` array if they need to be used as numbers.

Comment: @Bergi - `parseInt` and `parseFloat` will both give back actual numbers whereas numbers coerced/cast with `Number` are in a weird interim state where `typeof` will identify them as an object and npt as a number. It may not necessarily be germane to this particular question, but it's worth consider.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the data is part of an DOM object, I don't see the point of using jQuery.

```
var myData = 
{
"data" : 
    {
        "Count" : ["1","2","3","4", "5"]
    }
}
var countAry = myData.data.Count;
var results = new Array(countAry.length);


for (var i = 0, il = countAry.length; i < il; i++) {
    results[i] = Number(countAry[i]) + (results[i - 1] || 0);
}

myData.data.Results = results;
console.log(myData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = [];
var data = myArray.data
for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + 1 ) {
   val = i == 0 ? 0 : myArray[i-1]
   myArray.push(data[i]+val)    
}
console.log(myArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the ECMAScript 5 Array methods: Assuming `json` is your json data...

```
var sum = 0,
    count = JSON.parse(json).data.Count.map(function(i) {
      return parseInt(i, 10) + sum;
    });
```